# Can any one tell what is wrong with this Dialog?

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog

I have this dialog But when I call it it gives me this error :
**Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart': Failed assertion: line 453 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true.**,
My Code:

```
return showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: Text(msg),
        actions: [cancel, ok],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Your context is null

Comment: just check if the widget is in the tree and getting the context, else if it somewhere else just pass the build context to that function.

Comment: I already defined it above otherwise it would show me that it is not defined.

Comment: Don't you get warnings for using a deprecated function?

Comment: Check that you're not using it inside the build() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you *exactly* what's wrong: your variable `context` is `null`.

You need to provide a `context` that is not null.

You should also provide `builder` instead of a `child`, because that way to build a dialog is [deprecated](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) for good reason.

Comment: I tried to add builder but ut is the same, about context should I define it outside the function ?

Comment: You should pass a valid context. Since I don't know anything about what you actually did or what your code looks like, it's hard to say. Please edit your question to contain a [mcve], not just a snippet.